# Type has no field or method

Tags: go, methods

I have a problem with a struct's method.
In one file (same package) I a struct:

```
type Task struct {
    ID       int    `json:"id"`
    Priority string `json:"priority"`
    Content  string `json:"content"`
}
```

The Task comes as a body in POST. Parsing the JSON to this struct works well.
In other file I have a method:

```
func (task *Task) createTask() (err error) {
    data, err := bson.Marshal(&task)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("error in parsing incoming task")
    }
    rslt, err := collection.InsertOne(context.Background(), data)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("error in saving task to database")
    }
    fmt.Println(rslt.InsertedID)
    return nil
}
```

The Task structure is in the same file with my server. createTask() method is in the file which handles communication to mongoDB.
When I run my server I have this error:

```
./server.go:53:12: task.createTask undefined (type Task has no field or method createTask)
```

Here is how I am calling the method:

```
var task Task
json.Unmarshal(body, &task)
err = task.createTask()
```

Do you have any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "When I run my server I have this error" but this is a compile time error not a runtime error. How are you building your software? Use `go build` only and keep away from `go run`.

Comment: @Volker Well I am still at beginner level and was always trying to run, not to build. Building solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @mgalazka `go run` will compile only those files that you pass to it, so if you want to execute a quick test run you need to feed all of the package's files to `go run`, e.g. `go run main.go file_with_method.go`, alternatively you can also do `go run .`, using a "pattern" to match all files in the current directory, etc. more info here: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program

Comment: No problem. `go run` is a _helper_ and is _unsuitable_ to properly compile an application as it is too easy to use it wrongly. `go run` is the perfect tool to run a single-file application, often some helper or code generator which is often even excluded from the actual build. And `go build` is used to build go programs and go packages.

Answer (score 0):

This got me as well >.<

Go only considers functions that begin with a capital letter to be exported; including member functions. So you need to change:

```golang
func (task *Task) createTask() (err error) {
   ...
```

to

```golang
func (task *Task) CreateTask() (err error) {
   ...
```

and similarly at the call site.

Go's error unfortunately doesn't tell you how to fix this if you wrote the module and intend for the function to be exported.